# What did Una McCormack have to ignore to write The Autobiography of Kathryn Janeway?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager, fandom

I was listening to the latest episode of the Transporter Room 3 podcast, [Star Ship Down review](http://transporterroom3.blogspot.com/2021/09/212-deep-space-nines-starship-down.html). It contains an interview with Una McCormack, who wrote The Autobiography of Mr. Spock. She also wrote the The Autobiography of Kathryn Janeway.

When talking about Captain Janeway ([link to the podcast](https://hwcdn.libsyn.com/p/b/f/b/bfb8736c5bd84021/TR3-212.mp3?c_id=112187891&cs_id=112187891&expiration=1633082608&hwt=53a8d3b3cc26a1604bdcb63fa7e8ab25)), at 23:34, she says:

> Once we decided not to stick with the **indecipherable word**.

I cannot for the life of me figure out what she's saying, and how it relates to Captain Janeway.

Can anyone explain and why she chose to ignore it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indecipherable word is "Mosaic" which she repeats a few seconds later.

> "**Mosaic**" could possibly also refer to the Star Trek Voyager book
> [*Mosaic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(Star_Trek)) written by Jeri
> Taylor, which features Janeway reminiscing about her life before
> Voyager. It presumably covers a lot of the same ground as *The
> Autobiography of Kathryn Janeway* and so a decision would need to be
> made about whether to treat it as canon or invent a new story.

Hat tip to Princess Ada for the comment reproduced above.

Comment: I guess it's her accent. Thanks!

Comment: "Mosaic" could possibly also refer to the Star Trek Voyager book Mosaic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosaic_(Star_Trek) ) written by Jeri Taylor, which features Janeway reminiscing about her life before Voyager. It presumably covers a lot of the same ground as the Autobiography of Kathryn Janeway and so a decision would need to be made about whether to treat it as canon or invent a new story.

Comment: Thanks @PrincessAda I've edited to quote you. Hadn't heard of that 'till now.

Comment: Honestly, I'd just delete the first (wrong) paragraph of this answer if I were you.

Comment: Wait, put back the sentence that stated the indecipherable word. It's not clear how Mosaic is the answer.

Comment: That's two embarrassingly wrong answers I've given in one day, apologies. @Valorum

Comment: Valorum beat me to it. @EmpressSvetlana

Comment: @ARogueAnt. - That's why I never post anything (usually) unless I can back it up with evidence.

Comment: Every time I post whilst distracted I cut corners like this without thinking. Basically I don't multitask well and should stop trying. @Valorum